# Mazda 6 MZR-CD diesel fuel issue

Tags: engine, fuel-system, mazda, diesel, pressure

I have a mazda 6 mzr-cd turbo diesel wagon 2009 model. I just purchased the car and after trying to jump the car i thought the engine had no compression. However after trying again with a stronger battery the engine seemed like it wanted to start but it wouldnt. I used starter spray into the intake and after cranking it for a while i got it to start however it wont stay on. I unplugged the fuel line to the injector to and tried to crank to see if diesel was coming out, however it was coming out but very minimal amount and it doesnt spray. I have tried to figure out why diesel is not pumping into the engine, if anyone could help me out. My brother checked with a computer to see if the cluster had been changed because he informed me that if an ecu is changed then the cluster and key has to go with it else it will not start. Any suggestions to as why the diesel wont pump into the engine and why the pressure is low?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not completely familiar with how Mazda does their diesel, but it appears they do it much like anyone else. It appears there are two pumps: 1) low pressure at the tank (lift pump); 2) High pressure which feeds the common rail (where the injectors sit). If I were a betting man, the high pressure pump is not working and you're getting the dribble from the lift pump. *Why* HP pump would stop working is unknown. Could be the ECU isn't starting it or it could just be dead.

Comment: I also searched the error codes i got from the diagnosis and the code was b01da-62. After researching that and finding what causes that was 2 things. The thing that i have my focus on is a faultt body control module, apparently the symptoms of a faulty body control module can be engine not cranking and a faulty BCM can cause the B01DA-62 fault code to come up. Does this sound like it could cause the high pressure pump not to engage? I will maybe take to it to technician to check out the BCM.

Comment: No. The BCM should be completely separate from engine management. The BCM is primarily for control of the body stuff, like ensuring there is power to the electric windows, keeping power to the radio after engine shutdown for a period of time, and the like. It shouldn't have anything to do with the function of the HP fuel pump (to my way of thinking). The problem could also be in the relay for the HP fuel pump. You might try jumping the relay contacts directly to see if you get any  pressure at the rail.